# Singleton Bean in EJB 3.0 not referenced from another Ejb in a different Jar file

Tags: ejb-3.0

I have an EAR having 
    Example.war , ExampleEAR.jar , /lib/persist.jar
.
 Now during start up of the server there is an StartUpEJB.java which gets started as its annotated with @Startup. Now StartUPEJB is referring to PersistMgrEJB.java which is present in persist.jar file. But I am getting the below error.

Caused by: javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: An error occurred during initialization of singleton session bean ExampleEAR#ExampleEJB.jar#StartUPEJB , resulting in the discarding of the singleton instance.; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The EJB reference in the StartUpEJB component in the ExampleEAR.jar module of the ExampleEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface com.test.myejb.PersistMgrEJB not present in application ExampleEAR.
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.NoSuchEJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:511)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of the module deployment by specifying it in *application.xml*.

```
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order> 
     <display-name>Example</display-name> 
     <module> 
         <ejb>persist.jar</ejb> 
     </module> 
     <module> 
         <ejb>ExampleEAR.jar</ejb> 
     </module>
     <module> 
         <web> 
             <web-uri>Example.war</web-uri> 
             <context-root>Example-war</context-root> 
         </web> 
     </module>
```

In EJB 3.1, there is support for initializing dependent components using [@DependsOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/DependsOn.html) annotation.